# Fast search-insert-delete algorithm for low power processor

Tags: c++, search, sorting, vector, dictionary

We have a application that run on a low power processor that needs to have fast response to incoming data. The data comes in with a associated key. Each key ranges from 0 - 0xFE (max 0xFF). The data itself ranges from 1kB to 4kB in size. The system processes data like:

```
data in
key lookup -> insert key & data if not found
buffer data in existing key
```

After some event, a key and associated data is destroy'ed.

We are trialing a couple of solutions:

1. Pre-allocated `std::vector<std::pair<int,unsigned char *>>`, that looks up a key value based on the index position.
2. `std::map<int, unsigned char *>`
3. Red-Black tree
4. `std::vector<...>` with a binary sort and binary search of the key's

Are there any other algorithms that could be fast at insert-search-delete?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you going to have duplicates for a single key, or will new data with an existing key replace the old data?

Comment: Since you're talking about very small datasets (1-byte key) on a low power processor, you should definitely disregard thinking about traditional algorithmic performance and big O notation for algorithms.  Remember all of that applies only as datasets grow towards infinity.  Practical performance for small sets doesn't follow those patterns.  Do 1) or 2) and profile the performance

Comment: @Mark - single key, new data is buffered against that key

Comment: @TJD - Thanks for Big O comment. Never quite thought of it like that.

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` uses a balanced tree (like red-black tree) itself, so there is no point in re-implementing it.

A sorted `std::vector` with binary search has the same performance of a balanced binary tree. The difference is that placing a key in the middle of the vector is costly.

Since your keys have a very limited range, your best choice is similar to your first suggestion:

```
std::vector<unsigned char *> data(0xFF);  // no need to have a pair
```

This way, a simple check of `data[key] == NULL` shows you whether data for this key exists or not. If it was me, I would even make it simpler:

```
unsigned char *data[0xFF];
```

Comment: Why does the array have to be dynamically allocated? I'd go for `unsigned char *data[0xff]`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, Oops, I meant that one! Not being dynamically allocated was one of the reasons I changed it to array from vector in the first place!

Comment: @Shahbaz - Thanks - the low tech C way was totally forgotten :) I think I was over complicating it all...

Answer (score 1):

If the key is in the range `[0, 0xFF)`, then you could use this:

```
std::vector<std::string> lut(0xFF); //lookup table

//insert 
lut[key] = data; //insert data at position 'key'

//delete 
lut[key].clear(); //clear - it means data empty

//search
if(lut[key].empty() )  //empty string means no key, no data!
{
   //key not found
}
else
{
    std::string & data = lut[key]; //found
}
```

Note that I used empty string to indicate that data doesn't exist.

Comment: How would you associate the data element with the key?

Comment: @user626201: See my updated answer. let me know if you're any doubt.

Comment: Using `lut[key].empty()` is more direct than comparing to an empty string.

Comment: @Nawaz - Thanks - the data in binary not string, would the `std::string` not drop those bytes?

Comment: @user626201: Depends how you intialize it. You've to use a-pair-of-iterators, or simply use `char*` instead of `std::string`, or you could use `std::vector<char>` also in place of `std::string`, in which case, the lookup table would be of type `std::vector<char*>` or `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` depending on what type you choose for binary data. You may define your own struct/class if you want to add more functionality.

Comment: Not enough people realize that `string` and `vector<char>` make good substitutes for `char*`. Using `string` has the disadvantage that an assignment stops at the first null character, not a good choice for binary data; `vector<char>` doesn't take a `char*` assignment and forces you to initialize it properly.